# mysql_query wont update if the String value contains a comma (,)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Why is it, that I can't UPDATE a field (type:longtext) with a string that contains a comma (,)...

```
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET column1=$a WHERE column2=$b AND column3='price'");
```

Works well with

```
$a="10"; or $a="10.99";
$b="15";
```

doesn't work with

```
$a="10,99"; 
$b="15";
```

neither works with:

```
$a="10,99";
$a=mysql_real_escape_string($a);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your query string is being evaluated with the values that contain commas, this is the query:
`"UPDATE table_name SET column1=10,19 WHERE column2=15 AND column3='price'";`
The comma is creating an issue because the value 10,19 is not a string. You need to put quotes around your variables. If you use double-quotes, you will need to escape the quotes. Single quotes work as well; either of the following should do the trick:

```
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET column1=\"$a\" WHERE column2=\"$b\" AND column3='price'");
```

or

```
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET column1='$a' WHERE column2='$b' AND column3='price'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change (you need to wrap string or text type of field with `'`)

```
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET column1=$a WHERE column2=$b AND column3='price'");
```

To

```
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET column1='$a' WHERE column2='$b' AND column3='price'");
```